# Jekyll and Hyde researchers?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> **Jekyll and Hyde researchers**
>  Faced with questions requiring knowledge they do not possess,  policymakers in the public – or private – sectors have  no other choice than to turn to  ‘wise men’  to underwrite the merits of their decisions.  But when researchers leave  their laboratories to give advice and guidance,  they are changing functions and moving into the field of expertise.  This doubling up is not without a certain amount of ambiguity. Of course scientists are required to base their advice on objective facts.  The link between pleural cancer and exposure to asbestos is amply demonstrated – even if it took a  long time for this truth to express itself.  Such a straightforward cause and effect scenario is, however,  not the usual case in any scientific expertise.  The boundary between the objectivity of the data and the subjectivity of the responses derived from them remains to a great extent blurred and uncertain. This movement of contemporary science is paradoxical: the more knowledge breaks new ground,  the more it gains in complexity,  and the more diversified the issues inherent in this very  complexity become.  20th century quantum physics established the unique concept of ‘the uncertainty principle’  – that the very  observation of a phenomenon generates uncertainty as to how to measure it.  This concept can be extended to virtually every area,  with science being both a judge of and a party to the advances it makes possible.  And the accumulation of knowledge is constantly challenging established certainties,  with a large portion of discoveries drawing their inspiration from a perpetual questioning of established concepts… 
> Source: research*eu No.62 Feb 2010 (The magazine of European Research Area)

Jekyll and Hyde means someone who is sometimes nice but at other times is unpleasant. I didn't understand where they mentioned researchers as Jekyll and Hyde.

Answer (score 3):

Although 'Jekyll and Hyde' often characterises people who can switch between good/evil, nice/mean, in a broader way it can simply mean a split personality - someone who has two different behaviours, perhaps in different contexts.

In your example, it talks about scientists who, in the context of their science work must behave objectively and to the scientific method, but the same people may be called on in an advisory capacity on matters where the science is not complete and this may require them to behave differently, to offer more subjective responses.

Answer (score 1):

More specifically, *Jekyll and Hyde* means a person with a dual identity.

The job of researchers is to question established knowledge, but when they are called upon to advise policymakers they have to appear as 'experts' and make definite statements about scientific facts.